# Train from non-numeric data to predict a string column in new data set - Python Machine Learning module

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

So my problem is:
For eg existing data set A:

```
host, procpath, type, segment
abc, C:\test\w.ini, mp4, movie
abc, D:\test\w.tmo, mp3, song
def, C:\test\tx.563, mp4, movie
efg, U:\test\w.ini, mp4, unknown
```

Now I have a new data set B:

```
host, filepath, type
abc, D:\test\w.ini, mp4
abc, E:\test\w.tmo, mp3
efg, C:\test\tx.563, mp4
abc, U:\test\w.ini, mp4
```

*All of the data fields are strings (non-numeric) in A & B datasets.*
*Obviously A & B datasets are not this small. Data Frame shape 4000x23.*

I want to ***predict*** “**segment column**” for the new (B) data set **using existing (A) dataset** above.

Comment: During preprocessing, you should convert your non-numerical data to numerical data before building a model to make predictions.

Comment: Thanks, I am totally a new person to this ML field. I am still learning, would be great if you can post up a link/ex, to help with what you are recommending.

Comment: A good site to get your feet wet is [this one](https://pythonprogramming.net/)